# How can I get a Codemirror tokens parent form?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

How can I get the parent form from a codemirror token?

I've tried this but it does not work because `nodeName` is undefined.

```
var form = cm.parentNode;
while (form.nodeName != "FORM" && form.parentNode)
    form = form.parentNode;
alert(form.id);
```

If I can get the token's textarea, then the above code would work.

Comment: Please create a complete working example (snippet/jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the parent form without using the codemirror token.

```
var form = event.currentTarget;
while (form.nodeName != "FORM" && form.parentNode)
    form = form.parentNode;
alert(form.getAttribute("id"));
```